# Docusaurus anchor links suddenly not working

Tags: markdown, documentation, docusaurus

Is there any reason why my anchor links don't work? That is, they don't go to the header they're supposed to go to; you click and nothing happens.

It's especially strange because a few of them do work, but the rest do not. Not even the same link, where one works but the others in the same md file do not.

I haven't tried anything other than checking the syntax and putting the links other places to see if they work (nope).

I tried searching to see if any others had the same problem, but I couldn't find anything.